# How can i load existing project in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I downloaded the project from web , now i extracted it. How can i load this project into eclipse environment ?  do i need to use import and then existing android code into workplace ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use File -> Import -> General -> Existing Project Into Workspace and then find your zip file.